# Unable to build react-native iOS build. 'Analytics/SEGAnalytics.h' file not found

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, segment-analytics

Running macOS Mojave and
Xcode version 9.4

When I try building my react-native iOS app either on command line or in the Xcode project, it fails with the following error:

```
/Users/padminipyapali/Development/archipelago/react-native/aloha/node_modules/@sonder/analytics-react-native/ios/RNAnalytics/RNAnalytics.m:10:9: fatal error: 'Analytics/SEGAnalytics.h' file not found
```

Steps I followed:
1. In react-native project directory, ran 'yarn install'
2. In iOS directory, ran 'pod install'
3. In react-native directory, ran 'react-native link'
4. In react-native directory ran 'react-native run-ios'

Tried react-native unlinking and relinking the segment analytics library, and got a different set of errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NEHotspotConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNWifi.a(RNWifi.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NEHotspotConfigurationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNWifi.a(RNWifi.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get the same error in the CLI and in Xcode.

Expected the build to run on my simulator, without the crash.

Comment: try to follow this sequence: create new project and copy your package.json file ... run yarn install ... link your npm modules ... and the last step is to `pod install`

Comment: analytics-react-native probably wasn't installed properly. I'd recommend you do a manual linking instead.